# Matching CNcontact and Digits Find Friends Swift 3

Tags: swift, cncontact, twitter-digits

I am trying to build iPhone App with digits Find a friend feature

I can get list of matching `digitUserID` from Digits.

Now I am struggling to match `UserID` and `CNContacts`.

Please point any examples to deal this.

As update:

```
do 
{
    try contactStore.enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest(CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactMiddleNameKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey,CNContactPhoneNumbersKey])) {
        (contact, cursor) -> Void in

        self.results.append(contact)
    }
}
catch{
    print("Handle the error please")
}
```

The above I have managed to get all contact but I don't know how to pass a phone number filter into this and get exact contact match with `CNContact`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ideally, one would have expected `predicate` of the `CNContactFetchRequest` to do the job, but that (still; argh) only accepts a narrow list of predicates defined with `CNContact` (e.g. `CNContact` `predicateForContacts(matchingName:)` or `predicateForContacts(withIdentifiers:)`. It doesn't even accept the block-based `NSPredicate`.

So, you have to enumerate through, looking for matches yourself, e.g.

```
let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: [
    CNContactGivenNameKey as CNKeyDescriptor,
    CNContactFamilyNameKey as CNKeyDescriptor,
    CNContactMiddleNameKey as CNKeyDescriptor,
    CNContactEmailAddressesKey as CNKeyDescriptor,
    CNContactPhoneNumbersKey as CNKeyDescriptor
])

do {
    try contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: request) { contact, stop in
        for phone in contact.phoneNumbers {
            // look at `phone.value.stringValue`, e.g.

            let phoneNumberDigits = String(phone.value.stringValue.characters.filter { String($0).rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits) != nil })

            if phoneNumberDigits == "8885551212" {
                self.results.append(contact)
                return
            }
        }
    }
} catch let enumerateError {
    print(enumerateError.localizedDescription)
}
```

Regarding matching "digit UserID", I don't know what that identifier is (is it a Contacts framework identifier or Digits' own identifier?).

Comment: oh that's my own identifier.

Comment: Would it be possible  to modify the answer to include a search string (name, telephone, email)? If not, could you point me to another solution. Thanks

Comment: @DavidDelMonte - Sure. If it were a simple search, you could supply a [`predicate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontactfetchrequest/1403080-predicate). But I don't think that will search inside phone numbers, so you may have to add an `if` statement inside your `for` loop, checking for your searched string in whatever fields you want. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42749708/1271826.