# How to fetch contacts NOT named "John" with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, contacts, cncontactstore

Is there a way I can fetch contacts using the [Contacts framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/contacts) *without* an attribute?

Example:

```
myContactArray = unifiedContactsNotCalled("John")
```

PS: I know that line is nothing like the real code, it's just a serving suggestion for illustrative purposes

Comment: FWIW, I don't think this is "too broad." If you know the Contacts framework (and the challenges it entails), this question is perfectly clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before I outline how to find those that don't match a name, let's recap how one finds those that do. In short, you'd use a predicate:

```
let predicate = CNContact.predicateForContacts(matchingName: searchString)
let matches = try store.unifiedContacts(matching: predicate, keysToFetch: [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName)])    // use whatever keys you want
```

(Obviously, you'd wrap that in a `do`-`try`-`catch` construct, or whatever error handling pattern you want.)

Unfortunately, you cannot use your own custom predicates with the Contacts framework, but rather can only use the `CNContact` predefined predicates. Thus, if you want to find contacts whose name does not contain "John", you have to manually `enumerateContacts(with:)` and build your results from that:

```
let formatter = CNContactFormatter()
formatter.style = .fullName

let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName)])   // include whatever other keys you may need

// find those contacts that do not contain the search string

var matches = [CNContact]()
try store.enumerateContacts(with: request) { contact, stop in
    if !(formatter.string(from: contact)?.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchString) ?? false) {
        matches.append(contact)
    }
}
```